# What is Difference between BPMN2 Model and Generic BPMN2.0 Diagram in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, bpmn, business-process-management

I have installed the Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler 1.3.0 Plugin (by RedHat) in Eclipse (Neon).

While trying to create a new BPM, i see 2 options (BPMN2 Model and Generic BPMN2.0 Diagram). [image: New BPM Options]

> What is the difference between these ?